# How to start a Flutter app after tapping a hardware button after a number of times?

Tags: flutter

Hey can anyone assist me in letting me know what to use to effectively start a flutter app from hardware detection?

I see that there's a hardware detection plug in but this only works when the application is open. 
I'm trying to get the app to automatically start or display an Alert Dialog Widget after tapping say the power button after 3 times.

I am not sure what technologies/plugins to use. Can anyone assist?

Comment: I don't see how that is possible without writing some sort of native app to do that.

Comment: What if a platform channel is used for the native code to communicate with the flutter side of it?

Comment: Is there any progress on this subject?